# Any possible method to detect click on cross-domain iframe on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

been a few weeks trying different ways to detect a cross-domain iframe click on mobile without success.
I have tried all that has come through, all plugins, all forum tips, and yet i can't get a way to do it.
I coded whatever way i through will work and i got no positive results.
Some plugins are working on newest phones like s6/7 (maybe for other older phones too?) using blur events but i need a reliable solution that will work with most to date phones.
Maybe there is a workaround with touchstart function for mobile..
I lost my chances into believing that there's a way to do it so today i am asking here maybe someone figured it out.
Thank you.

Ps this is a demo of a plugin called iframetracker.
Can someone tell me if it works on old mobiles? http://cdn.rawgit.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer in short is **No**.

Regarding your plugin, on the github, it states very clearly:

> **About mobile devices**
>
> This plugin doesn't work on mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets, because this hardware uses a touchscreen instead of a mouse as click input. This design makes the boundary monitoring trick useless

This is why you won't find a solution for your issue.

There is no known work around for your particular problem with touch screen devices.